# Python: Pip command is not recognized

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Here is a screenshot I took.

[image]

When I try to use `pip` in command prompt I get the following error message:
`pip` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I already checked this thread: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

All I could find there was I had to add `"C:\PythonX\Scripts"` to my classpath, where `X` stands for python version.

As you can see on my screenshot I already have this path. I already tried restarting the computer but that didn't work, o.O. The screenshot also shows my `C:\Python27\Scripts` folder.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you open a new DOS prompt? Also print what `echo %PATH%` says for you.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran: OP said they restarted the whole computer

Comment: @jdi - sorry that escaped me.

Comment: The variable should be `PATH` (not `Path`), and does not have any spaces between the separators (the `;`).

Comment: echo %Path%
Returns  "C:\Python27\Scripts;" in the end.

Comment: Lol, it was the space. I feel so stupid now.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: The space is problem, but the case doesn't matter

Comment: Is `easy_install available` for you? Also, what is the error that is being thrown?

Comment: @user1303142 You should answer the question, and mark your answer as accepted and close the question :)

Comment: @SenthilKumaran 

The problem was the space. After I removed it pip is recognized.

Comment: @user1303142 - glad that it worked for you!

Comment: Refer: [add pip to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097258/2142994)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: This question should have been closed as a typo at the time; redirecting it as a duplicate now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a space before the last path entry, right after the previous semicolon, that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Go to `C:\Python27\Scripts`

Now select the url bar and replace whole content with `cmd`

This way you directly reach to the directory where pip is available in command prompt

Now type  `pip install Django==1.8.5`
it will download and install Djanog

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem, but typing your command *in* the "Scripts" folder fixed it!

In other words:

1. Open command prompt (right click windows start menu and click on "Command Prompt (Admin)"
2. Use "cd" command to change directory to where python is installed, but go to your scripts folder (for me, this is `cd C:\Program Files\PythonXX\Scripts` where the XX is the version number of Python)
3. Once in "Scripts" folder, type `pip install cython` and press enter

Answer (score 2):

what I did is for example in the command prompt or cmd in windows:

```
py -m pip install pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

It started working for me when I added ; in PATHEXT  after .PY

Answer (score 0):

1) browse here - `C:\Python27\Scripts` 
2) open the cmd window/terminal (shift+'right click') 
3) type `pip install django`

Comment: What's the difference here with arvind kumar's answer?

Comment: 2nd step, a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

1) open cmd as an administrator

2) enter: cd c:\python27\scripts (go to python and shift right click on folder. Than copy to path)

3) press enter

4) pip install

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "your python path"\Scripts to PATH variable. See [How to set path variable](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)
2. Don't forget to restart the command prompt.

Now pip will work in any path.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Python Script Path, copy the path, go to CMD and type cd "paste the path you copied".

type pip --version

You will see the version of pip your system is running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have python installed properly.
2. next install pip using

a) Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a folder on your computer.

b) Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing get-pip.py.

c) Run the following command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Pip is now installed!

3. Copy the path of executable file in environment variable. It is the Script folder path where python is installed. like
   C:Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts OR
   C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Programs**\Python\Python35-32\Scripts**
4. Restart your command prompt and its done