# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, django, windows, pip

I'm running into a weird error when trying to install Django on my computer.

This is the sequence that I typed into my command line:

```
C:\Python34> python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...

C:\Python34> pip install Django
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python34> lib\site-packages\pip install Django
'lib\site-packages\pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What could be causing this?

This is what I get when I type in `echo %PATH%`:

```
C:\Python34>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\S
ystem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\
Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Mana
gement Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine C
omponents\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components
\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\P
rogram Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x
86)\git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsIn
staller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Users\Javi\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: You may need to add pip to the PATH environment variable. Otherwise CMD prompt doesn't know what you're talking about

Comment: Hmm I'm relatively new to programming have only done some ruby on rails. Can you explain a bit more what you mean by PATH environment variable? How?

Comment: @fr1tz I get a huge output... seemingly a really really long directory of files

Comment: @user3597960 do you know the location of your pip installation? You need to add this location to that really really long list of directories, which is actually the PATH system variable. To add it to the PATH variable you can either use `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\pip"` for example or you can add it via the control panel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53870/discussion-between-fr1tz-and-user3597950)

Comment: if the path of your Python\Python37-32\Scripts is too long like mine C:\Users\IT-admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts then command terminal trim the path and won't allow the addition of full path. In this case use the 'Advance system setting' from control panel to add manually as shown in screenshot by @KarthikeyanVK in below answer

Comment: `py -m pip install [package_name]` worked for me in PyCharm terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: pip: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780717/bash-pip-command-not-found)

Comment: In windows `right click` on `My Computer` or `The PC` then click on `properties` then on popup window go to `Advance System Setting`  or `Advance` in win7 then click on `Environment Variables` then check `System variables` section and find ` Path` click on it then click on `Edit` and add the `Script` folder path here. The script path is most likely like this `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts` find your and add that here.

Comment: 2023 and we still have to edit path variables. why is this so shitty?

Answer (score 772, accepted):

**You need to add the path of your pip installation to your PATH system variable**. By default, pip is installed to `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip` (pip now comes bundled with new versions of python), so the path "C:\Python34\Scripts" needs to be added to your PATH variable.

To check if it is already in your PATH variable, type `echo %PATH%` at the CMD prompt

**To add the path of your pip installation to your PATH variable**, you can use the Control Panel or the `setx` command. For example:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"
```

---

**Note**:
According to the [official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28v=ws.11%29.aspx), "[v]ariables set with setx variables are available in future command windows only, not in the current command window". In particular, *you will need to start a new cmd.exe instance* after entering the above command in order to utilize the new environment variable.

Thanks to Scott Bartell for pointing this out.

Comment: This gives `"Fatal launcher error: Can't create execution environment"`

Comment: @fr1tz, the command did not work when being added from the cmd utility. I had to add it manually from system settings>advanced>environment variables. I am using Windows 8 64bit. Thanks!

Comment: After this, you need to install any package from that Directory i.e. C:\Python34\Scripts (For example) pip install openpyxl

Comment: Note: you'll likely need to close and reopen your CMD prompt after you run the setx command.

Comment: For python 3.5 installed on Windows 10, the path is: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35

Comment: It worked but why the added is not showing in `system settings>advanced>environment variables>system variables>path`?

Comment: does this apply no matter where you actually installed python on your machine? and I can't find "AppData" under username file. also running on windows 10.@derek

Comment: _By default, pip is installed to_ -- by who's default?

Comment: do not forget to change version of python, for me it was `Python27`

Comment: [Windows 10] If the path set is not working you can run it to navigate to the script folder run with pip3.7.exe
C:\Users\<USER NAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip3.7.exe install django==2.0.2

Comment: In my case the path location was "C:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts"

Comment: And yes, you don't have to add the "\pip" after the directory. Its sufficient to have it know till the Scripts.

Comment: @AlexGordon by the default specified by the Python installer (in the case of this Q&A, the Windows installer for Python 3.4).

Comment: For VS: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64

Comment: I don't have/Scripts/ in my Python310 folder

Comment: `setx` truncates strings, and will only tell you _after_ it's done it, see [here](https://superuser.com/q/387619). It warns you but does it anyway before you can abort. This makes this method a _real gamble_ because you better be prepared to have your PATH messed up if you have a lot of software. The default limits might have been increased since (I don't know by OS versions), but you should be aware of this limitation.

Answer (score 329):

For Windows, when you install a package, you type:

```
python -m pip install [packagename]
```

Comment: I think these are the docs for the command `-m`: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=m#cmdoption-m

Comment: `'python' is not recognized`. I have it installed on my windows 10

Comment: @vsync Try 'py' instead of 'python'

Comment: This particular solution is great for Virtual Environments :)

Comment: @Marian07 Your suggestion seem to be the only one that's working. I have tried some of the other suggestion about uninstalling pipenv because the virtual environments conflicting, not working. Thank you!

Comment: "py -m pip install [package]" in VS Code

Comment: @vsync you had to include the python version folder. You probably only ended at the python folder. What I mean is, you should add this to your path environment variables "C:\Users\DJOTCHUANG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38" not this "C:\Users\DJOTCHUANG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\". 

This is for Python 3.8. You should include your own path of course.

Comment: This is far and away the best way to do it. It is platform-agnostic, works transparently with virtual environments, and - most importantly - doesn't require trying to figure out *what the path is* to *the correct* instance of `pip`. As long as `python` finds a (properly installed) version of Python, `python -m pip` means "the pip intended for use with the Python that is found by `python`".

Comment: It's amazing that the Windows installer doesn't set all these paths up? Surely that would be job 2 after getting you the files for python?

Answer (score 241):

As of now, version 3.7.3 I had a little bit of an issue with getting the right system variable.

Try this:

1. Type `start %appdata%` in cmd.
2. After that file explorer should pop up in `../AppData/Roaming`.

Go back one directory and navigate to `Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts`.

[image]

NOTE: The version number may be different so if you copy and paste the above file path it could not work.

After you do this you now have the correct location of your downloaded Python. Copy your file path by selecting the whole directory in the address bar.

[image]

Once you do that click the start icon and navigate to the *Control Panel* → *System and Security* → *System*. Then click *"Advanced System Settings"* on the left side of the panel.

Once there, click Environment Variables on the bottom right and there will be two boxes, an upper and a lower box. In the upper box: Click on the 'Path' Variable and click <kbd>Edit</kbd> located on the right. Click <kbd>New</kbd> and paste your directory Path. It should look something like this:

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> three times, open a *new* window of cmd and type: `pip`. See if it works.

Comment: Just wanted to highlight how comprehensive and helpful this was. I hope people link to it.

Comment: remember to restart the command line. It didn't work till I had done that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Especially useful for those who use Anaconda to locate where the pip file is when Anaconda was installed just for one user on the computer. And for those of you who are quick to alert me that Anaconda has a powershell too. I know. It doesn't like CLD2.

Answer (score 86):

For me the command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts
```

worked immediately (try after **echo %PATH%** and you will see that your path has the value C:\Python34\Scripts).

Thanks to: *[Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows/9546345#9546345)*

Comment: This seems to work just as long as you don't close the cmd, setx will do it permanently

Comment: I really don't see how this deserved a seperate answer a year after the selected one.

Comment: @fr1tz this answer worked for me but not the previous one

Comment: @gma992 I can't understand how. This answer says to do the exact same thing that the selected answer says to do, i.e., to modify the `PATH` environment variable in the same specific way. The only difference between `set` and `setx` is [which terminal sessions are affected](https://superuser.com/questions/916649).

Answer (score 54):

The only way that worked on my Windows 10 machine was as follows:

```
py -3 -m pip install xxxxx
```

Answer (score 49):

**Alternate way.**

If you don't want to add the PATH as the previous well written answers pointed out,

but you want to execute pip as your command then you can do that with `py -m` as prefix.

Given that you have to do it again and again.

eg.

```
py -m <command>
```

as in

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Also make sure to have `pip` and `py` installed

[image]

Comment: While following this advise, I discover that my python installation had a "(1)" at the end of the .exe file name. After deleting the extra characters, python began wirking as expected

Comment: I think these are the docs for the command `-m`: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=m#cmdoption-m

Comment: i already installed python how can i add pip now?

Answer (score 26):

Also, the long method - it was a last resort after trying all previous answers:

```
C:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install [package].whl
```

This after cd in directory where the [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) is located.

Answer (score 21):

As per [Python 3.6 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

> It is possible that pip does not get installed by default. One
>   potential fix is:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Comment: This command will solve the issue on windows

Comment: I used this command but now if I install any package in base or my virtual environment, it automatically installs it in both. even if i create a environment, by doing pip list, it shows all the packages installed in base. How can I undo it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! It worked (I don't care about the different environment issues suggested)!

Answer (score 17):

Control Panel -> add/remove programs -> Python -> Modify -> optional Features (you can click everything) then press next -> Check "Add python to environment variables" -> Install

[image]

And that should solve your path issues, so jump to command prompt and you can use pip now.

Comment: this worked for me on windows 10 laptop with latest OS, i was using CMDER as my emulator

Answer (score 14):

Try going to Windows PowerShell or cmd prompt and typing:

```
python -m pip install openpyxl
```

Answer (score 14):

Go to **control Panel >> Uninstall** ***or*** **change Program** and double click on **Python XXX** to modify install. Make sure PIP component is checked and install.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem just now.

After adding the proper folder (`C:\Python33\Scripts`) to the path, I still could not get `pip` to run. All it took was running
`pip.exe install -package-` instead of
`pip install -package-`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I have windows 10, 64 bit, 4 apps (problem probably partly comes from this fact) anaconda3 2020.11, python 3.7.0, python 3.9.1, python launcher.

Answer (score 10):

In latest version Python 3.6.2 and above, is available in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts

You can add the path to our environment variable path as below

[image]

Make sure you close your command prompt or Git after setting up your path. Also should you **open your command prompt in administrator mode**. This is example for Windows 10.

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
set Path = `%PATH%;C:\Python34\;C:\Python27\Scripts`
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/windows/)

Answer (score 6):

I tried all these methods and watched so many YouTube videos regarding this and nothing work for me.

Finally I tried this way and it worked.

In my case only the Pip was only not identified.

Go to this site. https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Download that file by right clicking on that page. Create a new folder and put that file in to that folder. Navigate to that folder and open cmd inside that folder. Then type.

```
python get-pip.py
```

After that, it will start to download. Like this in SS.

[image]

After successfully installed, close cmd and run again the cmd and type

```
pip --version
```

then in my case of course it shows like this

[image]

it worked. Most of these solutions related to setting the path in environmental variable . But my case in script folder there wasn't any file to be seen. I think the most easiest way is uninstall python through setup and delete other pip things then create new pip installation. if it isn't working the path setting to the environment variable refer this YouTube video. ([Copied from Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PikcUT-ts7E))

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76804535/edit) (it covers text program output in answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Or if you are using [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) (2017-03-03) like me, just change directory in terminal and install:

```
cd C:\Users\{user}\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts
pip install ..
```

Answer (score 5):

`'pip'` is not recognized as an internal or external command

pip is a Python module used to install packages. For your problem, there can be many reasons;

- Restart CMD/Terminal
- An environment variable is not set. pip is installed, but an environment variable is not set. A environment variable is a Windows variable where the pip path is saved, so it can be run at run time.
- pip is not installed.

### Restart CMD/Terminal

It is sometimes possible that you opened your command prompt or terminal before installing pip and now it just needs a restart to pick up the latest environment variables. It is worth trying just restarting your command prompt or terminal.

### Environment Variable is *not set*

Open CMD and run this command to see the values set in the PATH environment variable.

```
echo %PATH%
```

This will echo the PATH environment variable like this;

[image]

You should check if your path exist in the echoed PATH list. For example, in my case, the path for pip.exe files is `C:\Python310\Scripts`. You can check this path yourself like this;

[image]

If you can find pip path and it does not exist the echoed PATH variable, then we need to add it. Copy the path like `C:\Python310\Scripts`.

> Go to Start* → *This PC* → *Properties* → *Advanced System Settings* → *Advanced* → *Environment Variables*

[image]

As shown in the image above, select Path, click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button and add the copied path. Restart the CMD and test pip command again.

### pip is *not installed*

If pip is not installed, you can install it again by downloading latest `python.exe` setup from the *[python.org](https://www.python.org/)* website. Make sure you check mark the pip option as shown in the image below.

[image]

In the next step, check mark "Add Python to environment variables"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Even I'm new to this, but `pip install django` worked for me.

The path should be set as where the script folder of the Python installation is, i.e.**C:\Python34\Scripts**.

I suppose it's because Django is a framework which is based on Python, and that's why this directory structure has to be maintained while installing.

Comment: It is better to set pip in environment variables. Your method would make it restricted.

Answer (score 4):

I have just installed Python 3.6.2.

I got the path as

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts

Answer (score 4):

**In Windows**, open cmd and find the location of PYTHON_HOME using  `where python`. Now add this location to your environment variable PATH using:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<PYTHON_HOME>\Scripts
```

Or [refer to this](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

---

**In Linux**, open a terminal and find the location of PYTHON_HOME using `which python`. Now add the `PYTHON_HOME/Scripts` to the PATH variable using:

```
PATH=$PATH:<PYTHON_HOME>\Scripts
export PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try `pip3`. Something like:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 4):

Most frequently it is:

in `cmd.exe` write

```
python -m pip install --user [name of your module here without brackets]
```

Answer (score 4):

None of these actually worked for me, but running

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

and then adding the specified directory to the PATH as suggested got it working

Answer (score 3):

I think from Python 2.7.9 and higher pip comes pre installed and it will be in your scripts folder.

So you have to add the "scripts" folder to the path. Mine is installed in `C:\Python27\Scripts`. Check yours to see what your path is so that you can alter the below accordingly. Then go to PowerShell, paste the below code in PowerShell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. After that, reboot and your issue will be resolved.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27\Scripts", "User")
```

Comment: The OP is using Python 3.X, not 2.X.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. Run Windows PowerShell as **Administrator**. It resolved my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your Python folder path in Terminal, just type

```
  py -m pip
```

in order to check the current version of your pip.
You will also see a list of commands, you can use...

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67517688/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Windows: the only solution that worked for me is:

1. Navigate to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
2. Copy the path
3. Open *Environment Variables* → *System Variables*
4. Paste

   [image]

After that, PIP should work correctly!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a Windows environment, just execute the below commands in a DOS shell.

> path=%path%;D:\Program Files\python3.6.4\Scripts;
> (new path=current path;path of the Python script folder)

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the older version using the control panel and then installed the new version however the newer version was not reflecting pip even after adding the right paths in the environment variables. However, the thing that worked for me was deleting the folders of old python that were there in the local App folder even after uninstall. For me, the path was like below. Deleting this folder solved my issue

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python38
```

Answer (score 2):

**First of all, check the `pip` version, and its existence on machine**

```
 pip --version
```

or

```
 pip3 --version
```

If you in case `pip` is not installed then install it.

**On Linux, you can install pip3 by running an apt-get command in your terminal.**

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

**On Mac, pip is bundled with the Python distributable, so you need to re-install Python**

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3 && brew install python3
```

**On window this issue occurs when `pip` is not correct in the PATH file**

You can try below `py` prefix alternative to make it work

```
python -m pip install [packagename]
```

**To set `pip` PATH [Reffer to Ani Menon Answer for details]**

Find the location of PYTHON_HOME using

```
where python
```

Now add this location to your environment variable PATH using

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<PYTHON_HOME>\Scripts
```

Or

**On Linux, open a terminal and find the location of PYTHON_HOME using**

```
which python
```

Now add the `PYTHON_HOME/Scripts` to the PATH variable using:

```
PATH=$PATH:<PYTHON_HOME>\Scripts
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows users:
Open your Python's scripts folder; it's usually located in this path:
 `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<VERSION>\Scripts`, 
for example: `C:\Users\elyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts`.

Then, see if there is a pip executable file, if you don't see one, run this CMD command: `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

If you do see a pip executable file, look at it's name, and run it in CMD. For example, I have a pip3.exe file, so in CMD I run `pip3`. If the command is not recognized, then make sure the scripts folder is in the system's PATH variables:

1. Open CMD in Admin mode
2. Run this command: `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`
3. Under system variables, edit Path to see its content.
4. Make sure the Python folder and the Python's scripts folder are present. If they are not in the list - add them.

Answer (score 0):

Small clarification: in "Windows 7 64 bit PC", after adding `...Python34\Scripts` to the path variable, `pip install pygame` didn't work for me.

So I checked the "...Python34\Scripts" folder, it didn't have `pip`, but it had `pip3` and `pip3.4`. So I ran `pip3.4 install pygame .... .whl`. It worked.

(Further open a command window in the same folder where you have the downloaded `pygame...whl` file.)

Answer (score 0):

I continued to receive this error after correcting my PATH.

If your codebase requires that you have an earlier version of Python (2.7 in my case), it may have been a version prior to the existence of pip.

It's not very canonical, but installing a more recent version worked for me. (I used 2.7.13.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. You just need to go to your

> C:\Python27\Scripts

and add it to environment variables. After path setting just run pip.exe file on C:\Python27\Scripts and then try pip in cmd. But if nothing happens try running all pip applications like pip2.7 and pip2.exe. And pip will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to get around this is to open the path where pip is installed in [File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer), and click on the path, then type cmd, this sets the path, allowing you to install way easier.

I ran into the same issue a couple days ago and all the other methods didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall Python, delete the remaining program files, and then install it again fresh.

It worked for me. This error happened to me when I migrated to a new laptop and used a migration software to move my software from the old laptop to the new one. And yeah, it didn't work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the system was not *restarted* after adding the below in PATH:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

When installing [SQL Server 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2019) Python, there are known issues for PIP which require a fix (step 7). See
*[Known issues for Python and R in SQL Server Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/known-issues-for-sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15)*.

'pip' is configured with locations that require [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)/[SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), however the ssl module in Python is not available.

```
Workaround
Copy the following files:

libssl-1_1-x64.dll
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

from the folder
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Library\bin
to the folder
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\DLLs

Then open a new DOS command shell prompt.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, run the below command in a terminal window:

```
echo  export "PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can we resolved very easily.

First of all, you have to check if the pip is installed or not with Python.

For *that*, you need to follow following method.

1. open the Python installation directory

   ```
   pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages\
   ```

   We suppose that you have installed Python on the C: drive in the 'python34' named folder.
   This will be definitely different for you.
2. Under the 'site-packages' folder, find the pip folder. If it is, then all is set. You just need to go for the next step.

   If not, just refer to [this tutorial to install it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/).

Now Pip is installed in our system, and you just need to configure it.

1. Open the Python installation directory:

   Here copy the path of the installation directory.
   For example:

   ```
   C:\python38;
   C:\python38\Scripts;
   ```

   Here I am assuming that python is installed under the 'C:\python38' directory. Please change accordingly.
2. Now in Windows, click on the start button and search:

   Environment Variable
3. Open edit the "System Environment Variables" option.
4. Under *User Variables*, choose *Path* and open it by clicking.
5. Now click on <kbd>Add new</kbd> and just add the above copied path one by one.
6. Save it and close all tabs.
7. Open *cmd* and type

   ```
   pip -V

   pip -V
   pip 20.2.3 from c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
   ```

Now it works.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where a screenshot *is* appropriate (for the Windows environment variable settings part).

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Before taking any drastic measures, it's a good idea to check your current Python installation:

Open a terminal or command prompt.
Run the command `python --version or python3 --version` to check your Python version. Note it down.
Now, try running `python -m ensurepip --default-pip` (or use python3 instead of python if that's your primary command). This command will attempt to bootstrap the installation of pip if it's missing.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Jeferson Andrade's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270199/1519716) answer from over 6 years ago.

Answer (score -5):

If you are working with Python, e.g. [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), you should install the library to the Python library path like this:

```
pip install --target=C:\Users\<...>\lib <Library-Name>
```

real e.g.

```
pip install --target=C:\Users\devel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib requests <br>
```

PS: If you want to check if it's installed,

```
<Library-Name> --version
```

will not work correctly.

Comment: Please add code blocks when answering questions, this makes it very difficult to read.