# How to get Easy_install and Pip on windows 7

Tags: python, django, windows-7, pip, easy-install

I am a beginner and i can't find what is the problem with Easy_install and Pip on windows 7. Probably Pip would be fine if i could use Easy_install.

I have downloaded these: Setuptools 5.7 and get-pip.py
I saw that everything was installed, also i found everything in Python2.7 folder.

But every time i wright command:

> easy_install pip

or

> pip install Django==1.6.6

i always get back 'command not found' or 'easy_install' is not recognized as the name of cmblet ...

What is the problem? Maybe i should delete all and use another tutorial? Please guide me, i have been stuck here for days! :D

Comment: yes, and i saw many files being downloded

Comment: Just did, but it doesn't read my commands "pip help" or other

Comment: Just found out that when i try to install 64bit version it tells i don't have python! And my OS is 64bit. Should i try ti install Python 64bit and then your link 64bit?

Comment: what is "32 bit bin"?

Comment: Okey, as i understand that can't be a problem. My python code is running fine on interpreter, only i can't use any package (pip ...).

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to type:

> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"

I hope it will help someone else too. 
here is link where i found answer!

['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-installing-django-w)