# Using pip Python 2.7 - Pipe not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-win32.**whl**
I read it is necessary to use the pip to install such file extension. 
So I downloaded python 2.7 which already comes with pip installed. 
However when I try to execute the following command:

```
pip install Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

command prompt returns:

```
pip is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

**EDIT**

I tried the following solution:

['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

But the message result is the same

Comment: Probably answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Refer: [Add to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097258/2142994)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the directory containing `pip.exe` to your `PATH`. It is usually found in `C:\<PythonInstallDir>\Scripts`, probably `C:\Python27\Scripts` unless the installation method has changed recently. The method of editing your `PATH` varies slightly amongst Windows versions, so Google it with your particular version if you don't already know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **py -m pip install pillow** in the Command Prompt/PowerShell