# 'pip' is not recognized as a command

Tags: python, command, pip

I installed pip-8.1.1. The windows prompted that it was successfully installed. After I added 'C:\Python27\Scripts;' to Path in System Variables, the system still couldn't recognize 'pip' as a command.
Here is the error message: `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

How do I correctly add pip to Path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a new command prompt and run `pip` from that. Sometimes changes to environment variables don't propagate to already-open prompts.