# Why do i get this error when i use the pip install command

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install a package with pip(python) I ran up to a problem. I think it has something to do with the path because I did something with it. 
This is the error

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,  
      script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
      or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: your command prompt does not recognize pip. either you didnt install it or your path doesnt include it

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835341/pip-is-not-recognized)

Comment: Reinstall Python and select 'add to PATH'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized

Answer (score 2):

The executable "pip" is not in your system path. You can check your path variable using `echo %PATH%` and verify which executables are being searched for. If you provide some more details about your python installation (which version of python is installed, how it was installed and where), someone will help you install "pip" or add it to path.

Answer (score 0):

This would mean that you don't have pip installed, which is weird as it comes pre-installed with python. anyways you can get it by downloading from 
'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py'
then navigate to pip folder you just downloaded and run the command 
'python get-pip.py'
you can now verify if you got it installed correctly using
'pip -V'

Answer (score 0):

Add pip to your path by running this command in CMD with admin rights (replace the path "C:\Python36\Scripts" with your own python installation path) -

```
setx path "C:\Python36\Scripts;"
```

Restart your CMD and try pip again.