# pip is not working in the vs code i tried changing the environment variables.. i'm stuck with this

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

pip not working with any followed commands:

[image: pip not working with any followed commands]

pip is not showing anywhere:

[image: pip is not showing anywhere]

Comment: do you perhaps have it installed as `pip3` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36835341/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may not have pip installed, judging from your pictures. If so type this to check `python -m pip --version`.

If you don't have it installed, perhaps try `python -m pip install`.

If you do have pip installed and are trying to install pygame, I suggest trying `python -m pip install pygame`.

I also found that using `python` didn't work but replacing it with `py` did. I did these things (a while ago) in terminal on a windows 10 machine, so my suggestions may not be relevant.