# How to install ursina?

Tags: python, pip

I went to powershell and said pip install ursina, but the only thing that came up was

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ pip install ursina
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException \
```

What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835341/pip-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect one of 2 things

- Either pip is not installed in your computer(usually it comes installed with default installation of python )
- you have not added pip as a windows environmental variable under PATH

I would suggest re-installing python and then making sure that you have ticked the `add to path` option in the installation window

or type `sysdm.cpl` in the powershell window, this will open another window, in that window go to the **advanced** tab and select change **environmental variables** . Add the directory where you installed python under the PATH tab.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add python dir to %PATH%? Add it and try pip install ursina again. That should help.

also see ['pip' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835341/pip-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this issue is open the Python installer and press the modify option, check the "install" pip checkbox (other options are up to you), once you done press next, here check the option "add Python to environment variables", then you can continue your installation process.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install python3 `pip`
Then follow these commands for Linux;

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install ursina
```

if `install ursina` didn't work then try this;

```
python -m pip install ursina
```