# pip giving error when trying to install packages Python 3.10

Tags: python

I have been having issues with pip on Python 3.10 attempting to install a package gives me the following error

> pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try  again. At line:1 char:1

I have tried reinstalling pip and I have also tried reinstalling python.

Comment: have you tried pip3?
`pip3 install <package-name>`

Comment: This says that `pip` is not in your path.  Can you do `python -m pip install xxxx`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835341/pip-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up on windows when one tries to use pip in the command prompt. To solve this error on windows, you must declare path variable by following these steps:

Step 1 - Right click on My Computer or This PC
Step 2 - Click on Properties
Step 3 - Click on Advanced System Settings

You will find a section called system variables.
Click on Path from the list of variable and values that shows up there.
After clicking on path click edit.

You will find a New button in the pop up.
Click that and paste the location of the python35 or python36 folder (The location you specified while installing python) followed by “\Scripts” there.

For me its “C:\Users\a610580\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32”
so I type “C:\Users\a610580\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts”
Click Ok to close all windows and restart your command prompt.

I repeat - restart your command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This error is given by Windows, saying that pip is not found. It happened because Python isn't in your shell path, If you just installed Python, logout your user and log back in see if it resolves, if not, Python is not in your PATH.

For me, the most convenient way is reinstalling Python and checking every checkbox that says something like "Add python to PATH/environment variable" in the installer. You can also follow the other answer to add PATH manually.