# I'm trying to make a web browser again using python, when I attempt to run the code, this error message comes up. I'm using PyCharm

Tags: python, browser, pip

This is the error message that comes up when I install it in the terminal.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMumx.png

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Hunter\PyCharm Projects\Silic_Browser_Project\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835341/pip-is-not-recognized)

Comment: @MarkusMeyer
It didn't work

Comment: Can’t see any error message, could you edit your question?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE
I have edited it so that you can see what it shows in the terminal