# TqdmWarning: Iprogress not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am operating in a virtual environment in Visual studio code, using Python 3.10.0. After importing libraries in Python I get the following odd message right after the cell

```
c:\Users\user12345\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\tqdm\auto.py:21: TqdmWarning: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
  from .autonotebook import tqdm as notebook_tqdm
```

I go to the website that is mentioned in the error message. There it is instructed to `pip install ipywidgets` but when I run that command, I get another error message, this time in the terminal

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify th
at the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install ipywidgets
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I don't understand what this is, because I sure have pip installed. Then I checked in the command promt if I have pip, and there I get a message saying "Python is not found". So what is all this about?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835341/pip-is-not-recognized

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that the `pip` command is not recognized by your system. This can happen if Python or pip is not installed correctly, or if the PATH environment variable is not set up correctly.

You can use the following codes to check whether you have installed pip or Python:

```
   python --version
   pip --version
```

If you cannot see the version, you have to reinstall pip or Python.