# Upgrade version of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am running Python on a Windows machine at the following path:

```
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1
```

I am trying to upgrade to the latest version of pandas (currently running '0.17.1') but am having problems.

I have looked at previous posts and have tried on the command line using :

```
c:/>pip install --upgrade pandas
```

but just got `'pip is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'`.

Comment: How did you install pandas originally? Many people now use `conda`, part of the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: I think you can check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 135):

try

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: On Win10 as administrator

Comment: ran on Ubuntu 18.04 and worked fine

Answer (score 43):

**Simple Solution**, just type the below:

```
conda update pandas
```

Type this in your preferred shell (on Windows, use Anaconda Prompt as administrator).

Comment: This worked for me with the exception that I had to run cmd as administrator. Running on Windows 10.

Comment: @BobWakefield Yes you ll have to run it as Administrator.

Comment: this worked for me except i had to use the "anaconda prompt" on my windows 10

Comment: hi can this be run from any directory location or where the conda was installed initially?

Answer (score 3):

Add your C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1\python_***\Scripts folder to your system PATH variable by doing the following:

1. Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System, and select
   the Advanced tab.
2. Click Environment Variables. ...
3. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify
       the value of the PATH environment variable. ...
4. Reopen Command prompt window

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that is to run the code in the Jupitar notebook

```
 !pip install -U pandas
```

If it gives an error message ((**Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.**)) please add '--user' next the above code. as

```
!pip install -U pandas --user
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was solved by doing

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply ran conda cmd as admin then used

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

According to an article on Medium, this will work:

`install --upgrade pandas==1.0.0rc0`

Comment: Could you please add th elink to the article. If possible, please explain why

Answer (score 0):

I could not get conda to work.  Here was my command...

```
conda install pandas==1.4
```

It couldn't find pandas version 1.4 to download from anaconda.  However, I could get the following to work...

```
pip install pandas==1.4
```

Previously, I had pandas 1.2 installed and it automatically removed it before installing the updated pandas.  I hope this helps someone.