# Python: convert DAT files to XLS

Tags: python, csv, converters, xls

I have a bunch of DAT files that I need to convert to XLS files using Python. Should  I use the CSV library to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: Are all of the DAT files similar in format and if so can you show us a sample?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I do think they are all similar. If I can get at least 80% of the files converted with a simple script I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('DATA.DAT')
df.to_excel('DATA.xlsx')
```

and of course you can setup a loop to get through all you files. Something along these lines maybe

```
import glob
import os
os.chdir("C:\\FILEPATH\\")
for file in glob.glob("*.DAT"):
     #What file is being converted
     print file 
     df = pd.read_table(file)
     file1 = file.replace('DAT','xlsx')
     df.to_excel(file1)
```

Comment: I keep getting an error saying I'm missing the openpyxl module. I tried importing it, but still get the same error.

Comment: What version of pandas are you running? I think .to_excel is in v20? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954195/upgrade-version-of-pandas if you're running a version under 20.

Comment: not sure how to check version, I tried `pandas -version` but no luck. I ran `pip3 install --upgrade pandas` and it updated numpy to version 1.13.3; however, I still get the same 'no module found' error

Comment: ah, silly me, I didn't have it installed. It works now! Much appreciated Tim!

Comment: Wonderful! Glade to hear it :) And if you like it, can you accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to use the loop function, but I'm having issues. It keeps giving me the "No engine for filetype" error. I believe it has something to do with the `df = pd.read_table('file')`. Do I replace `file` with the name of the first DAT file in my directory? I've been trying this, but it gives me an error. I read something about having to use a temporary file, should I try using that?

Comment: Sorry, my fault the `df=pd.read_table('file')` should be `df=pd.read_table(file)` since file should already be a string. I've up-dated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_example.dat',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'strings_to_urls': False})
```

or you can use :

```
pd.to_excel('example.xlsx')
```