# How to set aggregation after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given that i have a dataset as below:

```
dt = {
    "facility":["Ann Arbor","Ann Arbor","Detriot","Detriot","Detriot"],
    "patient_ID":[4388,4388,9086,9086,9086],
    "year":[2004,2007,2007,2008,2011],
    "month":[8,9,9,6,2],
    "Nr_Small":[0,0,5,12,10],
    "Nr_Medium":[3,1,1,4,3],
    "Nr_Large":[2,0,0,0,0],
    "PeriodBetween2Visits" : [10,0,12,3,1],
    "NumberOfVisits" : [2,2,3,3,3]

}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dt)
```

i need to keep `groupby patient_ID`, then keep the `facility`,`patient_ID`,`NumberOfVisits`, but **Maximum** and **minimum** of `PeriodBetween2Visits`.

Here is what i tried:

```
dt = dt.groupby(['patient_ID'],as_index=False)["facility","patient_ID","PeriodBetween2Visits","NumberOfVisits"].agg({'PeriodBetween2Visits': ['min', 'max']})


dt.head()
```

But, it is not what i need!

A proper output for me as below:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your expected dataframe too? Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 please find my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using named aggregation here which was inbuilt in groupby and `agg` [recently](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html):

```
 dt.groupby(['facility','patient_ID']).agg(
                 Min_PeriodBetween2Visits=('PeriodBetween2Visits','min'),
                 Max_PeriodBetween2Visits=('PeriodBetween2Visits','max'),
                 NumberOfVisits=('NumberOfVisits','nunique')).reset_index()
```

---

```
    facility  patient_ID  Min_PeriodBetween2Visits  Max_PeriodBetween2Visits  \
0  Ann Arbor        4388                         0                        10   
1    Detriot        9086                         1                        12   

   NumberOfVisits  
0               2  
1               3
```

Comment: @Jeff might be a version issue. Is it possible to update pandas version? Which one are you currently using? `pd.__version__`

Comment: @Jeff I am using version `0.25+` , if possible please [`upgrade`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954195/upgrade-version-of-pandas) the version and try

Comment: @Jeff what exactly do you want to aggregate for that column, how do you get 2 and 3 in the example?

Comment: @Jeff I understand that but since we are reducing the rows we have to have some logic for rest of the colums, example either first row , max row avg, etc, you cant have all rows right?

Comment: Yes, we can consider first row value for `NumberOfVisits`

Comment: @Jeff then just use `NumberOfVisits=('NumberOfVisits','first')` instead of `NumberOfVisits=('NumberOfVisits','nunique')` for the 3rd aggregation