# Python: Expand JSON structure in a column into columns in the same dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a column consists of JSON structured data. My `df` looks like this:

```
ClientToken                      Data
7a9ee887-8a09-ff9592e08245       [{"summaryId":"4814223456","duration":952,"startTime":1587442919}]
bac49563-2cf0-cb08e69daa48       [{"summaryId":"4814239586","duration":132,"startTime":1587443876}]
```

I want to expand it to:

```
ClientToken                      summaryId         duration           startTime
7a9ee887-8a09-ff9592e08245       4814223456             952           1587442919
bac49563-2cf0-cb08e69daa48       4814239586             132           1587443876`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "My df looks like this" is df an instance of pandas dataframe? if no, what is df an instance of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df[["ClientToken"]].join(df.Data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x[1:-1]))))
```

**Explanations**:

1. Select the `Data` column and apply the following steps:

   1. Because the "`Data`" content is wrapped in a list and this is a string, we can remove `[]` manually using `x[1:-1]` (remove first and last character).
   2. Since the `"Data"` column is a `string` and we actually want a `JSON`, we need to convert it. One solution is to use the [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function from the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/json.html) module. The code becomes `json.loads(x[1:-1])`
   3. Then, convert the `dict`to a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) using `pd.Series(json.loads(x[1:-1]))`
2. Add these new columns to the existing dataframe using [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). Also, you will notice I used double `[]` to select the `"ClientToken"` column as a dataframe.

---

**Code + illustration**:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

# step 1.1
print(df.Data.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1]))
# 0    {"summaryId":"4814223456","duration":952,"star...
# 1    {"summaryId":"4814239586","duration":132,"star...
# Name: Data, dtype: object

# step 1.2
print(df.Data.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x[1:-1])))
# 0    {'summaryId': '4814223456', 'duration': 952, '...
# 1    {'summaryId': '4814239586', 'duration': 132, '...
# Name: Data, dtype: object

# step 1.3
print(df.Data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x[1:-1]))))
#     summaryId  duration   startTime
# 0  4814223456       952  1587442919
# 1  4814239586       132  1587443876

# step 2
print(df[["ClientToken"]].join(df.Data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x[1:-1])))))
#                   ClientToken   summaryId  duration   startTime
# 0  7a9ee887-8a09-ff9592e08245  4814223456       952  1587442919
# 1  bac49563-2cf0-cb08e69daa48  4814239586       132  1587443876
```

---

Edit 1:

As it seems that there are some rows where the `list` in `Data` has multiple `dicts`, you can try:

```
df[["ClientToken"]].join(df.Data.apply(lambda x: [pd.Series(y)
                                                  for y in json.loads(x)]) \
                    .explode() \
                    .apply(pd.Series))
```

Comment: Tried this:
df2 = df[["ClientToken"]].join(df.Data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0])))

After running this df2 contained 2 cols:
1) ClientToken 
2) Column name 0 with "["

Comment: Does the `"Data"` is a string representing a JSON or a real JSON ? Obviously, it's a string. I will update the answer

Comment: Thank you Alexandre!
Data is text. When looking at the df.info it is an "object"

Comment: I get the following error:
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 368 (char 367)

Comment: How does the line looks like ?

Comment: Sorry, what line?

Comment: The problematic line. I suspect there are same `Data` cell where the `list` of `dict` has more than 1 `dict` ?

Comment: df[["ClientToken"]].join(df.Data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x[1:-1]))))

Comment: I mean in your dataset

Comment: Emmmm. How can I know on which line?

Comment: My original df has Data content up to 3,000 chars long

Comment: Edit1 resulted in:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: As reported [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5381/files/2a94bc626903243ac54faa807c87a306fc01d796), you should consider update `pandas` to a version `>0.25`. For more detail on how to upgrade, see [Upgrade version of Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954195/upgrade-version-of-pandas)

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (1.0.3)

Comment: You want me to send you the df in any way?

Comment: What is the problem now ?

Comment: Edit1 resulted in: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Pandas is already the most updated

Comment: I think you're missing something about the version. Try, in the file you run, to add `print(pd.__version__)` and share the result, thanks

Comment: Well, you are right. The version is 0.24.2. However when I am running 'pip3 install --upgrade pandas' I get: Requirement already up-to-date

Comment: If you have several python version installed, be sure to run the appropriate one. Whatever, you can try to uninstall the current version and install the last one with `pip3 install pandas==1.0.3`

Comment: With Pandas > 0.25 this indeed works well!!
Many thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help you ! As you seem new on the website, maybe you can have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [ast literal eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import ast
d = defaultdict(list)
#iterate through the Data column and append to dictionary for each key
for ent in df.Data:
    for entry in ast.literal_eval(ent):
        for k, v in entry.items():
            d[k].append(v)

#concat to ClientToken column
pd.concat([df.ClientToken,pd.DataFrame(d)],axis=1)

    ClientToken summaryId   duration    startTime
0   7a9ee887-8a09-ff9592e08245  4814223456  952 1587442919
1   bac49563-2cf0-cb08e69daa48  4814239586  132 1587443876
```