# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"' (even though there are no spaces!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pip

I am using Python 3.5 and I'm trying to install some modules with pip, but I've had a bunch of difficulties. When I first typed pip install pandas into the Command Prompt, I got this error message:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I went to (['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)), and it said to add the path of my pip installation. So I typed the following into my command prompt:

`setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\sachg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts"`

This returned:

```
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

But now when I type pip install pandas, I get:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

Help?

Comment: Did you install pip properly? http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/

Comment: Shouldn't it already be installed when using Python 3.5?

Comment: I am not sure since i havent used 3.5, can you try this ?

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Comment: Actually I think I just got it to work- I just had to type C:\Users\sachg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pip install pandas. Earlier I was typing only pip install pandas, without the whole path

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just try

```
python -m pip install XXX
```

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command`
what i did is.. I have two python 3.5 and 2.7 environments on my machine.instantly its refer to  pyhon2.7 when i use `pip install XXX` or `python -m pip install XXX` so its update relevant packages in the python27 environment.
the solution for me was the change command to `python35 -m pip install XXX`(assumed you should set path environment for python35).
you can see update directory refer to python35
done