# PIP doesn't seem to be installing correctly

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5

I have updated my path for python 3.5.2 to its installation folder and installed pip manually through the get-pip.py file.

PIP is saying "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\MyName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages"

When typing pip into CMD, it is saying that it is not recognized. Any alternatives?

Comment: type echo %PATH% in CMD, and set the PATH system variable. See here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: @Aison I have successfully added PIP, looks like I forgot to add the "Scripts" folder to my path. When I type pip install packageName though, nothing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need adding pip.exe directory (C:\Pythonxxx\Scripts) to PATH Environment Variable in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Pip is not in your Path. The path variable is a place that holds directories for all your commands.  Including commands like python.  Right now it searches in all the directories listed in the Path variable, and when not found it will output a command not recognized error.

Windows:

http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Mac OSX/Linux:

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/

Answer (score 0):

You can either go directly to the dictionary of where Pip is installed, like Scripts on Windows. From that hold down the left shift button and right-click on it. Then click on "open command prompt here", something like that (depends on the language). Now you should be able to use every pip commands without an error.