# Can't install Django (or set up a virtual environment)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I am a beginner web programmer, and I am trying to start learning web app development on Python. I have Python 3.4 and I am using Windows 10. Python works fine when making a game using the pygame modules. Recently, I wanted to try web dev, and so I tried to install Django (along with creating a virtual environment), neither of which I was able to successfully do.

I've already installed pip as shown in the image below.

[Pip installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1N3V.png)

But for some reason when I enter into Command Prompt this:

```
C:\Users\Steven>$ pip install Django
```

I get:

```
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

OR

```
C:\Users\Steven\>pip install django
```

I get:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Also you can run pip as a python module: `python -m pip install django`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this issue on windows and here is what helped me. Before executing these commands please make sure that your system environment variable has **C:\Python34\** and **C:\Python34\Scripts\**. Also my Python version was 2.7.12 and I was using windows 8

First install virtualenv (skip if virtualenv is already installed)

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Then move to the directory where you want to create a virtual environment and hit this

```
virtualenv venv
```

Activate the virtual environment

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Install Django

```
pip install django
```

This should install django in your virtual environment. Now to start a django project the normal **django-admin.py startproject** did not work for me. This is what worked for me:

```
python C:\<PATH-TO-VENV-FOLDER>\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1. first check if python runs..  `python`
2. then install virtual env..    `python3 -m venv yourEnv_name`
3. now install django ..  `pip install django`