# Python:Install packages with pip; issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have problemm with downloading packeges. If I write in cmd:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

this happens:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I corrected my path beacuse of [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Here is what I get if  type `echo %PATH%`

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C
:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Compo
nents\TCS\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\Sy
stem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files
\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\e
asyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibr
e2\;C:\Python36\Scripts
```

But the same error keeps coming up, so any help will be appreciated!
Maybe I should also mention I have Python 3.6

EDIT:
If it's helpful, here is what hapens when I write:
import sys
print(sys.executable)

I get: C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe

**** are just cover for real name

Comment: Maybe you only need `C:\Python36` in your path and not `C:\Python36\Scripts`

Comment: Same error.....

Comment: If you go to C:\Python36\Scripts do you see a file called pip?

Comment: I can't even get to this file, as it says Windows can't find this file. Wow, haven't expected that, I also tried it with D:\Python36\Scripts...what should  do?

Comment: Add D:\Python36 to your path and remove the C:\Python36?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear...witd D:\Python36 it also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have pip installed?

Follow these instructions to download and install pip.

Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a folder on your computer. Open a command prompt window and navigate to the folder containing get-pip.py. Then run `python get-pip.py`. This will install pip.

Comment: This version should have pip. sorryy, I'm beginner and code you wrote doesn't work, I probably made some mistake...any idea where? I have this file on D disk, here is what I wrote: 
D:\>python get-pip.py
'D:\python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Pip should automatically be installed when you download Python 3.6 so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I have not written any code for you. Do you have the path to the file you downloaded?

Comment: @DavidG Whoops looks like I missed that line.

Comment: yes, file is correct, it's on disk D directly, not in any further file

Answer (score 1):

The link below explains the installation of Python and pip in Windows:

https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation

Basically, download and run the following command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: I did that and following error prints out:    'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

When calling echo %PATH% code shoud look like:

`blah blah long list of stuff;C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32;C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts`

To correct this use [GUI](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx).

All credit to:https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6evsaz/issue_with_pip/