# Anaconda install error

Tags: python, anaconda

I am begginer(self learner) in python and I face error while installing Anaconda.
Background:

1.I installed python 3.6.1 2 months ago(had isssues with correct path, but than [manually corrected it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328594/pythoninstall-packages-with-pip-issue))...I have also installed numpy, pandas, scpy,sklearn with pip

2.Now I started with tensorflow for which I need python 3.5. I uninstalled python 3.6.1, installed pathon 2.5.3 and cerrected path in environmental variables and pycharm(it works ok in Pycharm)

3.[I have issues with pip which I can't solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086435/pip-errorshould-upgrade-pip-pandas-and-matplotlib-but-returns-error)

4. So I realised Anaconda is only way to go. First I installed newest version(I also choosed to add Anaconda to PATH environmental variable. But I nistaleed newst version of anaconda so I had to uninstall and installed correct(4.2) for my python version.

Now same problem occures as to OP here:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/732

One solution mentioned here is to delete java path, but can't do that. I tried also some things mentioned in cmd, but don't work:

```
C:\Users\Uroš\Anaconda2>"C:\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe" -E -s 
"C:\Anaconda3\Lib_nsis.
py" addpath 3.6.1 Anaconda3 4.2.0 64-bit
This path can't be found.(*this is my translation, I don't have englesh windows 8.1)
```

Now I am beginner and don't really know what I'm doing, can anyone please check that github and gives me some(simple) advice as I tryied many things but don't work. So either I have different issue in background or I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install Miniconda first from [this](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html) link and later on download and install Anaconda then you ll be able to see navigator in your all programs in your start menu