# Using pip in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm having problems installing modules using pip in my Python 3.6. I've watched countless videos and read numerous posts about it amounting to nothing but frustration.

When I use pip in the CMD, it says:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip
>
> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: The error you're getting isn't related to python or pip - it's a general windows error. Try mashing your keyboard a few times in CMD, you'll end up with the same error. The question I've linked is the same answer, just replace _node_ for pip and/or python.

Answer (score 3):

Some information from official python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) page

> - pip is the preferred installer program. Starting with Python 3.4, it is included by default with the Python binary installers.

So, when you install Python 3.6 `pip` already bundled. `pip` is not windows executable, so you should use `pip` by following command

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

Comment: I actually tried that too.

C:\Users\Nirvan Mahat>python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you check "Add to path" when installing python? FYI you can also install pip to path during installation.

Comment: Make sure to **re open** your command prompt after installation. Because command prompt wouldn't recognize updated `PATH` in command prompt that opened before installation

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). In [Python 3.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html), it says that it is possible pip is not installed by default. The potential fix is:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Add the following to $PATH if they are not there:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
```

or Python36-64 if you installed the 64bit version.

Comment: Added the path you mentioned, still doesnt work. I installed it in 32-bit version

C:\Users\Nirvan Mahat>python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: That error means that Python is not in your path either. If you are not sure how to edit your PATH, I would just remove and re-install python from here https://www.python.org/downloads/

Click customize installation, on the first screen check PIP, on the second screen check Add to Enviornment Variables.

Comment: I just reinstalled Python with enabling the path to be python, and it worked!! Thanks

Comment: @NirvanMahat if case already closed please mark as answer