# pip not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I want to install Pillow for Python 3.6 but I'm having trouble installing it.
I'm on their installation page, https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
and all they say to download is "pip install Pillow" and nothing else.
So I tried to type that in my command prompt and all I get is,
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
So obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Pillow. Your issue is your system PATH not containing `pip`. In a command prompt window, what happens if you type `python` and press Enter? I suspect you'll get the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @roganjosh that would make sense the same thing happens when I type python. I do have Anaconda instead of python.

Comment: @roganjosh Nope, just Local, localLow, and roaming

Comment: No I don't see the "continuum" folder I do see a pip and conda folder though if that means anything. And I'm in a programming class we're using the pyCharm IDE for things like automating games and networking with python.

Comment: I've just been in a long chat in the chat room about my own issues with Anaconda and I think I've missed some points myself so I won't go further with my advice until I understand it better.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows then go to C: and search for python. A folder with user version number will be shown like 'Python37'. Open the folder and you'll see a folder named Scripts, open that, then you'll find pip.exe. Now copy the folder path and open 'Edit the system environment variables' in control panel. In that click on Environmental Variables and you'll something called path. Select path and click on edit, a window pops up, in that click and new and paste the directory address you copied previously. Save and exit everything. Now open cmd and type pip install [whatever].

Answer (score 3):

This command fixed my issue:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Comment: I used this command but now if I install any package in base or my virtual environment, it automatically installs it in both. even if i create a environment, by doing pip list, it shows all the packages installed in base. How can I undo it.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the complete path to pip -

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install <the library you want to install>
```

Example:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install numpy-1.14.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

or give the path to library you want to install as well.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install C:\Python27\pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved the problem.

I had to go into a terminal in my pyCharm, cd to a separate hard drive (Where I only store my work and games) then

```
pip install Pillow
```

and it installed perfectly fine and I got it working. I didn't install or move anything at all either. I'm just now curious as to why it decided to work in an IDE terminal and not my own cmd prompt. Oh well