# Installing libraries from any general directory using pip

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I need to install a new library using `pip`, I need to first go to the directory where the `pip` is located. The directory where `pip` is located is `C:\Python36`. But I can't install libraries from any other directory. When I do so, I get the error - `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps, 
for Windows 10 and Windows 8:

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
2. Click the Advanced system settings link.Click Environment Variables.
3. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit.
4. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable.[for you, 
   C:\Python36]

Click OK. 
Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.