# Problems with installing Python 2.7.14: Path to pip not recognized

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pip

While trying to install Python (version 2.7.14) on my laptop (Windows 10) today I ran into some issues.

See below an image of the command prompt:
https://i.gyazo.com/83c487ac3cf569006e4121d95fc1dd1f.png

After having tried to fix this myself for a while now I found out that the pip is indeed present, namely in a subfile of python27 (/Tools/Scripts), but is not recognized by cmd. How do I make sure pip is recognized?

For some additional info:
-the command prompt is ran as an admin
-this is not the default location for python to install (which is C: I think), instead I installed it in the program files, as was advised by my University.
-I feel like I might know the step of the installation which I did incorrectly, as the Scripts folder is mentioned specifically here. I simply did what the image 
 below suggested.
https://i.gyazo.com/a58d4f209b9d56f458d366355f2344ff.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated, have a good day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the (/Tools/Scripts) to the PATH variable.

For Windows 10/8/7:

1. Open System Properties (Right click Computer in the start menu)
2. Click `Advanced system settings`in the sidebar.
3. Click `Environment Variables`...
4. Select `PATH` in the `System variables` section
5. Click Edit Add Python's path to the end of the list (the paths are
   separated by semicolons). For example:
   C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27;**C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts**

Comment: Thanks a lot so far, definitely getting closer to the solution.
I successfully added the path to the System variables, which indeed seemed to be the right place as there were some other references in it (including a direct reference of \Python27\Scripts, which might be what's causing these issues initially).  https://i.gyazo.com/8ce5ca1889cefc1787e4d2a6c972f3b1.png (retrieved using set).
Still getting the same error however, having looked at the System Variables window for a bit I noticed PATHEXT did not include a .py extension, could this fix the issue (and is it save to touch?)

Comment: Here is a link that has details about installing pip .[link]https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation       As far as PATHEXT - I wouldnt touch it for now.