# Issue uploading a Python package to Pypi using Windoes 10 - twine is not recognized as an internal or external commend

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, twine

I have been trying to upload a Python package to Pypi. I have been following a couple of different guides. 
I have install twine using

```
 pip install twine
```

And it doesn't show any problem:

```
Requirement already satisfied: twine in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.0 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from twine) 
(40.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.14 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from twine) 
(4.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pkginfo>=1.4.2 in c 
:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from twine) ( 
1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from twine) 
(2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt>=0.8.0 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from twine) 
(0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from 
requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from 
requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from 
requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in 
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from 
requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (2018.4.16)
```

When using any kind of twine functionality like

```
twine upload -r pypitest dist/packagename-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

I am getting "'twine' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."" comment from the cmd.

I am using Windows 10. 
Should I create some sort of environment variable myself for twine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Yes you need to add twine as an environment variable. Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I'm using venv which is recommended. I added twine to /venv/bin/twine
Though I can't remember how, or whether it just sorted itself out.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem. And I am using Anaconda on windows 10, i.e., using Anaconda Prompt. After some searching, it is found that the **twine.exe** is located in the folder:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

From the output provided by you, I guess the **twine.exe** is located in your folder:

```
c:\users\amirh\appdata\roaming\python\python36\Scripts
```

Hence, you can add this folder path to your environment variable **PATH**:
System Properties -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH (Edit)

Then, reopen your Anaconda Prompt (or Command Prompt) and type

```
twine upload -r pypitest dist/packagename-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but the problem was not solved by updating the environment variable **PATH**.

I am on Windows 10, Anaconda3 and Python 3.9. [This tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) helped me a lot with packaging up and updating the package:

Here is the command instead of `twine upload -r pypitest dist/packagename-0.1.2.tar.gz`.

First upgrade the `twine`

```
py -m pip install --user --upgrade twine
```

Then, run `twine` to upload all of the archives under `dist`, using the following command:

```
py -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

See more in the tutorial I've referenced above.

Answer (score 2):

You may Try this instead:

```
     python -m twine upload -r pypitest dist/packagename-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your python scripts path as an environment variable in your user variables, besides the variable named "Path". This will make the things work perfectly for you as the twine gets installed within the scripts and so it must be passed to the environment variables, to access twine from any directory.