# How to install Python Pillow using PIP on Windows

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

Using Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10 (64 Bit) I am seeing the success message on installing pip from `get-pip.py` like:

```
E:\Software>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.0
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

but when I try to install Pillow from pip in continue

```
E:\Software>pip install pillow
```

I am getting this error

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: Hi Joel, same error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Python 3.4 and later already bundles `pip` so you don't have to install it separately; `python -m pip install pillow` should work just fine.