# How to install pygame for python 3.7.0 on windows 7(64-bit)?

Tags: python, windows, pygame

How do I install pygame for python 3.7.0  on windows 7(64-bit)? I tried using the pip install, and it always shows 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file. I watched many videos and they all show that in order to install pygame you need to use pip install.

What should I do? How should I download pip or is there another way to install pygame?

Comment: Use `py -3.7 -m pip install pygame` or add `pip` to your PATH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

When you installed python you were able to choose to add it to the PATH system variable, if you have not done this, pip will not work unless you navigate to its' location and run the command prompt from there.

You can search for pip.exe in windows to find it and then right click it and open the containing folder. Once in the containing folder right click anywhere and open command window here.

Alternatively you can just type 'cmd' in the path bar and hit enter, and this will open a command window in place.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install python and click the choose to add to PATH at the bottom of the first install screen.