# Pip not recognized as internal or external command (even after adding PATH variables)

Tags: python

I am trying to install Pip for Python, but am getting the internal/external command error:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have set my PATH variables (C:\Python and C:\Python\Scripts)

What's the issue here?

Comment: Are you using python 2.7?

Comment: Refer: [Add to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097258/2142994)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: pip needed to be installed to the C:\Python\Scripts folder