# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No Such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, installation

this is what I'm using to install packages, the only one that works is requests

```
pip._internal.main(['install', 'requests'])
pip._internal.main(['install', 'lxml'])
pip._internal.main(['install', 'cssselect'])
pip._internal.main(['install', 'selenium'])
```

this is the error message that i get in the console

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.7)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/c7/e088bf0f4f81e6b366cc2de12939c559b588b9525ad76215d122e69151ed/lxml-4.2.5-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-047sxufq\\9dca403282533c33ca73fe9ecbdb1b605aeffa273ec0704ef517f834'

Collecting cssselect
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/44/25b7283e50585f0b4156960691d951b05d061abf4a714078393e51929b30/cssselect-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-047sxufq\\e5cecb9a9f004e9bd84aa92925e0dc6e8458127d14eb08f37c4e2d0f'

Collecting selenium
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-047sxufq\\b3025a26893a7657747ef91c7e8a7d138021b8a645639c56cd0046c5'
```

i'm fairly new to python and just coding in general, i don't really know what these errors mean, and i couldn't find anything on google that i understood, so any help at all would be appreciated.

this is in visual studio code and on python 3.7.1

Comment: There is no reason at all that I can see to use `pip._internal.main(['install', 'requests']` and the rest. Open cmd prompt and type `pip install <library name here>`. If you're new to python, it's curious that you found this fringe approach that you're using; did you have issues with the standard approach?

Comment: @roganjosh when i used command prompt it said that pip is not recognized so i kind of just googled a bunch of stuff and i found that, which worked for requests but not the other stuff, and i wanted to be able to use this on multiple computers easily and i this was the best way i found.

Comment: Ok, this is not the correct fix. Did you install Anaconda or just regular python?

Comment: @roganjosh just regular python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized

Comment: @phd i got it working using command prompt! i'd still like to know why this error appears though..

Comment: Take the first of @phd links. That's the correct way to fix this. Your approach is fraught with issues.

Comment: @roganjosh i reinstalled python and i checked add python to environment variables and now it works, but I'd still like to know why this error appears when i run it like this.

Comment: `pip._internal` should ring alarm bells. The leading underscore is the universal python syntax for "don't use this variable or invoke this method directly". How _exactly_ it fails, I don't know, but the point is that you shouldn't be accessing it in the first place unless you _know_ what you're doing (nothing in Python is private, the best you can do is stick a "don't touch this" sign to methods and variables)

Comment: @roganjosh alright ill keep that in mind, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming late, but I guess this will help someone else who is facing a similar issue.

In the path:

```
C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-047sxufq\\b3025a26893a7657747ef91c7e8a7d138021b8a645639c56cd0046c5
```

The `"AppData"` folder and its contents are probably marked as `"Hidden"` and/or `"Read only"` by the Windows, unticking those and designating them as normal folders might help.

This is the only solution that helped me out. Please try it out and comment.