# what is the process of installing and working with PIL - Python Imaging Library ?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library

I tried installing PIL with pip it gives me this error:

> C:\Users\AppData\Local\pip>pip install
>   http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz 'pip' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

Comment: Have you installed Python on your Windows? What is the Python version?

Comment: yes.python version 3.7

Comment: Did you added path of your pip installation to your PATH system variable?

Comment: |If not check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @NishanthiniR try python --version on command prompt

Comment: PATH system variable means? @BusyBee

Comment: @SonalBorkar   I get this 
C:\> python --version
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\> py --version
Python 3.7.0

C:\>

Comment: C:\>py get-pip.py
(null): can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\>

Comment: @NishanthiniR you may need to include python installation folder to the PATH Environment Variable. Right click on This PC => Properties => Advanced System Settings => Advanced Tab and click on Environment Variables button. Edit the Path Key and add your python folder location

Comment: @NishanthiniR then run Command Prompt and try python --version

Comment: actually,py instead of python is working
C:\Users>py --version
Python 3.7.0

Comment: Thank you @SonalBorkar I got it

Comment: Welcome Nishanthini, Enjoy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I've had these issues as well. There could be many reasons, one of these should fix:

**1. `PIP` not added to system `PATH`**

This being the most common issue and is easily missed by new users. [check this for answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

**2. When you're using a python IDE such as `Anaconda` but haven't actually installed python directly**

You can open the `Anaconda Prompt` (in the Anaconda file group in your start menu) and then use `pip`.

**3. You have installed python for only the installing user (mostly admin)**

Your system has multiple accounts and if you have installed using `admin` or similar account and missed '`install for all users`', you'll need to open the `CMD` using '`Right click > Run as Administrator`' option with a valid admin username/pwd.