# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ...

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

I have two python 3 locations. One is located here,

"C:\Users\Ryano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32"

The other is related to Anaconda3 here,

"C:\Users\Ryano\Anaconda3"

I want run a .py file that uses the numpy package in the command prompt using the Anaconda3 python version. I go to import numpy and it doesn't recognize it:

> > > C:\Users\Ryano\Anaconda3>python
> > >
> > > Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 28 2018, 08:39:03) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
> > >       Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> > >
> > > import numpy
> > >
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

So I go to install the numpy package to the Anaconda 3 version python and this error pops up:

> > > C:\Users\Ryano\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install numpy
> > >
> > > Collecting numpy
> > >         Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/0e/5a8c34adb97fc1cd6636d78050e575945e874c8516d501421d5a0f377a6c/numpy-1.15.4-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl
> > >       Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\ryano\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib-1.0.1.dist-info\METADATA'

Looking at the other posts similar to this one I could not find any solution that worked for my computer. Essentially I'm having issues with installing using pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall `html5lib` with `conda`:

```
conda install html5lib
```

Comment: This worked! I uninstalled and then installed html5lib the way you said.

Answer (score -2):

There can be issues with using multiple installations on Windows.

Please check the answer to this question: [what is the process of installing and working with PIL - Python Imaging Library ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717401/what-is-the-process-of-installing-and-working-with-pil-python-imaging-library/53718337#53718337)

Hopefully one of the questions will fix the issue. If not, let me know.

Comment: The problem mentioned in this article is not being able to use pip. I can use pip, I just get an error when trying to install a package.