# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

i build my 1st module in python. but when i try to install the module it gives this error. Any idea how to resolve?

`D:\py scripts\Pi aoutomation>pip install timeCheck-1.0.tar
Requirement 'timeCheck-1.0.tar' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing d:\py scripts\pi aoutomation\timecheck-1.0.tar
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\py scripts\\Pi aoutomation\\timeCheck-1.0.tar'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717401/what-is-the-process-of-installing-and-working-with-pil-python-imaging-library/53718337#53718337)

However, in your case, you're trying to install a `*.tar.gz` file.

**You'll need to specify the absolute path of the file while using `pip install`.**

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install)

## Use:

```
pip install file:/absolute_path/timeCheck-1.0.tar
```

Comment: 2,I'm using idle.

Comment: 3. I have only one user account and i tried running the cmd as admin