# importing gTTS in python

Tags: python, text-to-speech

How can I install gTTS so I can use:

```
from gtts import gTTS
```

in python? I've tried it, and tried

```
pip install gtts
```

in cmd, but it says that pip is not a recognised command.

Comment: Try python -m pip install gtts if python is in your path ;)

Comment: You need to add the location of `pip` on your computer to your `PATH` system variable. Please refer to detailed SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 python -m pip install gtts
```

What the error means is that you do not have pip in your path.

Comment: Thanks,  now in CMD it says : Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\brunt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yd38di2k\gtts\setup.py) egg_info for package gtts produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=gtts fragments.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly Install pycharm ...then u can  install gtts or more libraries easily by using pip install command or with help of setting also

Answer (score -1):

You have to install pip, and then you can install gtts, and numpy, and anything else

Comment: welcome to SO, it is better write this answer in the comment