# How to enable pip in python?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'd need the commands in pip but I cannot enable them.
My python (python3.6.8) does not even recognise and highlight `pip` even though I have it installed in the script folder and enabled it while setting up.

I followed [this walkthrough](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-python-django-on-windows/) (twice) to be able to use `pipenv` but it still does not work. Please help

Comment: Make sure that the 'Scripts' folder is in your PATH.

Comment: I always wanted to ask `Did you try python3.6 -m pip` or `py -3 -m pip` ?

Comment: How to put my stripts folder in the my path? what to import for it?
I have both pi in the scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am also new here :)

From my knowledge pipenv and pip are two different things.

Did you launched your console as administrator?

Comment: Honestly I don't know the name. I only programmed in the file opened through the shell. Whivh one is that?

Comment: You wont be able to use pipenv. Pipenv its a new thing. This tutorial teaches about pip and Virtualenv, and not pipenv.