# Name and other errors

Tags: python

I'm running into a few weird errors using my python environment. It appears I was able to set up pip and python correctly in python 3.4.

I tried to follow a tutorial for hotkeys. I installed `pynput` in `C:\Python34\Scripts` using `pip install`.

Tried `'import pynput'` in Idle, worked fine without errors.

I then tried to install `keyboard`.

This time I got an error in Idle. Is there a strange reason why this module wouldn't go through without errors in Idle?  Another weird error I'm getting is:

```
'pip not recognized as internal or external command' in C:\Python34
```

Any idea why this is happening?  If I installed it in a higher directory like `C:\`, would this fix the issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you asking if it will be installed in higher directory when you can confirm it by yourself?

Comment: @pythonnovice please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command. You either need to run from the scripts directory or (better) add it to the path