# How Do I Install Pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, exe

I have tried several methods but i can't install pip, which i need in order to make my .py files into .exe files.

I have downloaded the get-pip.py and tried to run it in command prompt, it says it has installed but when i type: pip -V, it is not recognised. I have also tried editing environment variables in "My PC" properties.

py Desktop\get-pip.py
I have also tried it without the py
Desktop\get-pip.py

It says it is successfully installed but i cant use pip install pyinstaller for example and when i try pip -V it says pip isn't recognised

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure which version of python you are using but you need to add the location of the executable to your system environmental variables.
For python 2.7 you would click the start menu, search for environmental variables, open up the menu for that, click on the Path variable like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs5He.png)

and then add a new record for C:\Python27\ (for python.exe to be found by the shell) as well as C:\Python27\Scripts\ (which is where pip.exe should reside)

Comment: Make sure you select Path, click on Edit, and then click Add. Also verify the location of the executable. Another solution is to just run `python -m pip install [package]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall python and dependency
2. download python (for windows choose exicutable installer )
3. click on install and wait
4. when first wizard screen appear make sure u check the install pip check box in bottom
5. and remain process is same as u do