# Can anyone help me with some errors in pip installation? I downloaded get-pip.py but i faced some issues

Tags: python, installation, pip

I can see pip inside site-packages with pycharm but when i run in control panel pip --version it answers me pip is not recognized as an internal or external  command

Comment: use `python -m pip --version`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm, you can add libraries in your specific project via the settings menu. You don't have to manually install them on your global site-packages folder.

In your PyCharm project, go to File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter

Inside, click on the **+** sign and you will get to a window in which you can find and install basically every possible library you need.

Answer (score 0):

when it says `pip is not recognized` that means the location of the pip is not found. Try adding the location of the folder where the pip is present to the PATH in system environment variables (assuming you are using windows OS).

get-pip.py downloads the latest version of the pip from internet. So if you don't have working internet connection please download pip package from pypi https://pypi.org/project/pip/ and install.

Hope it helps.