# I installed python but my Scripts folder is empty

Tags: python, windows, pip

I downloaded python 3, and it works correctly on a basic script, but when i tried to import a package with pip in cmd, it said it didn't recognise "pip"

I'm on windows 10
I've tried to install different versions of python. I've also tried to install pip by itself at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.

When I try python -m ensurepip or python get-py.py i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 22312, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_internal\download.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\I56600~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkogcd_v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 64, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

C:\Users\I5 6600k\Downloads>pip
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\I5 6600k\Downloads>python -m pip
C:\Users\I5 6600k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Comment: Did you install pip (`python get-pip.py` -  as instructed in the page you posted)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708898/7334269](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708898/7334269)

Comment: yes I did Cristi

Answer (score 0):

Did you clicked to 'Path' when installing python? If no, then try to uninstall the python, and when edgy install of the python, click to add 'path'.

Comment: Yes i did check the box "add to path" when installing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. My system went through python installation and uninstallation couple of times. Also I created virtual environment few months back using pip. 
Recently when I reinstalled python, Scripts folder was empty. 
I searched for all Scripts folder from my root directory (This PC). I found some old Scripts folder containing pip packages. I removed those old Scripts folders, uninstalled python and installed again. Now it works.
I strongly recommend you to try this option. Don't forget to check "add PATH to env variable" option while installing python. Hope this helps.