# How do I use pip install?

Tags: python, web-scraping, cmd, beautifulsoup, pip

When I look up tutorials on Python almost every one starts with "Start of with `pip install bs4`" but they never tell me about how. Because when I write "`pip install bs4`" in my cmd the answer I get is only

`'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I've tried running "`pip install bs4`" in PyCharm as well but nothing works.

I am a totally a beginner, which you probably already noticed, and just want to get [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

Comment: you can folllow this:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows

Comment: What is the name of your Python executable? And are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're on Windows since your error message contains "batch file". Try:

```
py -m pip install bs4
```

The `-m` flag will import the `pip` module, and allow you to run the install command. If running `py` doesn't work, try the absolute path to your `python.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official site that shows you how to download and [install python pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

pretty much just download the file, open up the command prompt, cd to file directory and run it with:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: also if python command doesn't work try using python3 instead

Comment: make sure you've added python to PATH when you installed it btw