# I can't install pip

Tags: python, pip, prompt

I'm trying to download pip.

However, whenever I try the error I get is:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Another thing is that, when I use the command `python get-pip.py` I just get an enter and nothing happens. I have attached an image:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Use this command to install pip for python3: `sudo apt-get install pip3`

Answer (score 2):

It means pip is not yet available on your computer. To install pip on a debian linux distribution check the python version and use the following commands. For python2 if that is what is available on your computer.

```
sudo apt-get install pip
```

for python3 use

```
sudo apt-get install pip3
```

If you are on a windows os you will have to go a different fairly longer route. 
first you will need to install [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) on your device so refer to the links and install as they have highlighted in the instructions. After installing chocolatey open up your command prompt and run

```
choco install pip
```

With that you should have pip installed on your device and ready for use

Comment: you are welcome. Be sure to tick that it was your answer. I find that it makes it easier to find if you ever want to refer to it again