# Error 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, module, installation, pytube

I wanted to download Youtube videos with python and i opened Pycharm and wrote the code.
It gave me an error, saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pytube'".
I need to download Pytube, from Command Prompt, so i wrote "pip install Pytube" and it gave me this error: "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
How can I solve this?

Comment: pip is not in your PATH, re download python but select add pip to path

Comment: also im sure there are many other questions that answer this, don't run in here asking without doing your research

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: try doing `pip install pytube3`

Answer (score 0):

if python is registered in your PATH you can run

```
python -m pip install Pytube
```