# Disappearing pip as part of Python 3.8 installation

Tags: python, pip

Have reviewed the highly popular thread below, but cannot seem to find a resolution.
['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

I was having issues with the below issue, when trying to use CMD to pip install anything:
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Eventually was convinced it was my Python installation which may have been all over the place, so took the decision to completely remove and install fresh. Upon doing this, I managed to then successfully install something via 'pip install ', which in this case was pyinstaller.

However, having since turned off/on my PC, I now have the same issue again? When I go into my Python directory, there is no pip files/folder in :
C:\Users\Jon_D\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
C:\Users\Jon_D\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\libs
C:\Users\Jon_D\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib

In fact, there is now a pip folder within the higher Programs directory:
C:\Users\Jon_D\AppData\Local\pip

Not sure what has caused this given it was a completely fresh install, which included adding a PATH entry.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
python get-pip.py
```

If python doesn't recognise you can you py instead of python

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I tried both python and py, it suggests:
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, I'm not too familiar with windows, I can't help you on this issue, But I can give you one suggestion, if you really want to do something in python please switch to Linux or mac.