# VS Code Python pip is not recognized

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I just switched from PyCharm to VSCode, and when I try to pip install X, I get the following message:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a      
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install discord
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoun  
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I already updated the PATH, and when I do "echo %PATH%" on Command Prompt, I get the exact same directory as my PyCharm PATH directory. Why VSCode doesn't work, while PyCharm works flawless?

My PATH on cmd: "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts"

Comment: Which Python installation you used? If it is official CPython then it should work unless you have customized installation.

Comment: I am using Microsoft's Python extension on VSC, and downloaded the Python directly from python.org if you are asking that.

Comment: And can you open a new command prompt and run pip there? If you can run pip there, then it is problem with VSCode configuration. If you can't run pip in new command prompt then it is problem with PATH environemnt variable.

Comment: Yes, I can do pip install on windows command prompt, but I can't do it on VSCode terminal.

Comment: In that case going through some python settings for VSCode would be useful https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference . I suspect that ther might be .env file in your VScode workspace loading some different environment variables.

Comment: is it possible if I can use my pip install commands on command prompt, and import the installed packages on VSCode?

Comment: You can do that. But if VSCode can't find pip, then I suspect it can't find some other scripts required for linting and language support too.

Comment: What happens if  you set `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false`?

Comment: And BTW you are using PowerShell in VS Code, not Command Prompt based on that error message. If things are working under Command Prompt you could consider changing your shell in VS Code to Command Prompt explicitly.

Comment: Interestingly enough. Such an important issue. And yet there is really no fix to it. This issue may occur when you use VScode with or without Anaconda. After I have tried all the suggestions or solutions in either github or stack overflow...still to no avail. Please let me know if you have found a solution. Thank you!@yucecoder  PS. I also don't know if this has to do windows and VScode in general. I mean it's also nearly impossible to uninstall vscode from terminal.

Answer (score 29):

Try using `python -m pip` instead of `pip`.

Comment: That looks strange ... Did you install pip while installing python from python.org ? (it's optional). Because your error isn't due to VSC (python and pip don't depend of your editor), but to the fact that pip ins't installed or referenced in your PATH.

Comment: I just tried, and I can do pip install on windows command prompt, but I can't on VSCode terminal.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command), it possibly can help you.

Comment: My PATH is already like the one that is a solution for that thread. But I will make a better look tomorrow, maybe I am missing some details.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `py -m pip install apache-airflow` instead of `pip install apache-airflow`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a conda environment setup then try,

`conda install pip`

It worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

install latest version of PowerShell and try

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed Python on your OS. In my case, I fix it installing python using micosoft app store.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35809161)