# How can I properly set up pip to install requirements and run an executeable?

Tags: python, pip, fractals

First off, I have scoured stack overflow for questions that are similar, and these ARE ones I have seen, but they do not solve the solution for me and I have made sure to follow their steps.

- ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708898/12282360)
- List item

So, I downloaded [this](https://github.com/HackerPoet/PySpace) program to make an audio-reactive fractal, and in the readme it says the following:

```
## Installation

`'``bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
`'``
```

(I added in the two ' for formatting)

When I run pip install -r requirements.txt, I get the following error:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

All of the steps in the comments to the above mentioned post did not solve this for me. Even running python commands like

```
python -m pip install [packagename]
```

did not help me, it did not recognize python as a command either, so I reasonably assumed I did not have python, so of course I installed it and had no success in changing anything.

Later I found out that doing py instead of python fixed it, but the pip commands did not work and my attempts at installing pip completely failed.

I've been frustrated by this multiple times and have probably spent over 5 hours over the course of weeks trying to fix it. I really just need some methods to solve this.

Comment: what operating system are you using and how did you originally install python in the first place?

Comment: @khuynh Windows 10 - Installed via pycharm and later installing python 3.7 from python.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming pip is already installed on your device. Make sure that PIP is added to your PATH variable.

This link gives a detailed explanation on how to add the environment variable : https://appuals.com/fix-pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: Thank you - this is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> ```

Looking from your error message, I assume you're using Windows.

Because there's not enough information about your Windows version, if you're using Windows 10, you can use [Python 3.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/python-37/9nj46sx7x90p) from Microsoft Store, then install `pip` by downloading and running [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script.

After that, you can access `pip` by using `python -m pip`.

Answer (score -1):

install the PIP module using the `easy_install` command.
Open the cmd and type
`easy_install pip`.

Comment: easy_install not recognized.