# how to install pip on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I've tried installing pip on windows using instructions from https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/, (which I've listed below), but when I run pip -V, I keep getting `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Does anyone know what to do?

These were the instructions I followed:

1. Download get-pip.py to a folder on your computer. (right clicked and selected save link as...)
2. Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing get-pip.py.
3. Run the following command:
   python get-pip.py
4. Pip is now installed!

You can verify that Pip was installed correctly by opening a command prompt and entering the following command:

pip -V

Comment: Try `python -m pip -v` instead of just `pip -v`. This will ensure that you're referring to the same python you've used to install that pip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows you might find this article useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to uninstall python and then reinstall it again. In the installation window, use custom installation and check all the option which includes pip and also check to add pip to your environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, you need to add `pip` to the PATH.

This post should solve your issue: ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: I did ```setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts```, but do I replace C:\Python34\Scripts with the directory where I installed get-pip.py?

EDIT: I just tried but when I run pip -V I am still getting the same error