# python:installing Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, module, installation

I tried the command 'python -m pip install numpy' several times to install numpy on the command prompt but nothing happens. Can someeone tell what the problem is?

[image]

Comment: Happens only to 'numpy'?

Comment: haven't tried it for any other module, well I am using the command prompt for the first time, this worked on a video on youtube but not working with me

Comment: Hmm, try 'pip install numpy' or 'pip3 install numpy'

Comment: This will provide more details:
https://pypi.org/project/numpy/

Comment: 'pip not recognised as internal or external command it says'

Comment: That means you do not have pip install. Try a fresh installation of Python from the scratch. Download the .exe installer from their official website, and do 'check mark' the 'add environment variable' at the beginning.

Comment: something like this: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/python-3.8.3-amd64.exe

Comment: I chek marked the add environment variable while installing

Comment: Any progress after reinstalling Python. Close the CMD and open it once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install numpy` or `pip3 install numpy`

Or

Try a fresh installation of Python from the scratch. Download the .exe installer from their official website, and do 'check mark' the 'add environment variable' at the beginning.

Link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/python-3.8.3-amd64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: Did you use pip or pip3?

Comment: You need to add the path of your pip installation to your PATH system variable. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

On your CMD type python.
It will enter python and you'll see this sign (>>>), type 'import numpy'.
If it didnt install it you'll get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Then you'll need to type 'pip install numpy'.

If it did install it you'll see on a new line (>>>).

Another way to check if you installed it is by typing 'pip list' and see if it is there.