# I can't use pip in Python(Windows)

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have already download succesfully pip but I'm stilling can't use it. The terminal said:`'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
Please help me!

Comment: How have you downloaded pip? Is it downloaded with python? And, if yes, have you downloaded the conda distribution?

Comment: Check if you have pip downloaded, if so, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command.

Comment: Use the absolute path to your pip executable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

1. click on start
2. write "cmd"
3. right-click on "command prompt", and click on "Run as administrator"
4. wite pip and enter
5. if you see this message "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."" it means pip is not installed or not configured correctly
6. now go to the "edit environmental variable", and paste the path of "pip" in path section.
7. then try again from step 1

.