# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: while installing pyAudio in Pycharm

Tags: python, terminal, pyaudio

I do not know why i am getting this error,I have tried running the command `pip install PyAudio` in the terminal but shows error message:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Anyone know how to solve this, thanks!

Comment: Install pip https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably pip is not in your system path directory
you can check this link out for more info "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20add%20the,added%20to%20your%20PATH%20variable".

Answer (score 0):

Go in your IDE(Most probably Pycharm VS Code)
Open Terminal
Type pip install pipwin
Type pipwin install pyaudio
wait for the installation and done!
Don't forget to reload your project

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be a bit more legible? (use backticks for commands, add spaces between sentences etc...) Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

I would use anaconda.
In case you do not have it you can install it with

```
pip install conda
```

If you do not have installed pip then you can refer to the comment you already received by Thu Yein Tun on how to install pip.

and then run:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```