# Python scripts folder is empty?

Tags: python

I installed python 3.8.5 but the command pip not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file and folder scripts is not empty. Help me

[image]

Comment: Try `pip3` instead of `pip`...

Comment: but folder scripts not pip and pip3? not command

Comment: From your screenshot, the Scripts folder *is* empty. How exactly did you install Python3.8 and did you make sure it was installed correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)