# I do not know why I get the notification that pip is not on my computer

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I use Python on Visual Studio and when I try to run a code I get the notification that for example `Unable to import 'statsmodels.formula.api'`. So I thought that I have to install some extra packages. And what I understand is that pip should download the necessary packages. But everytime I go and look for pip I get the message `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: Have you installed pip?

Comment: I thought pip was installed automatically when I install python. Now I get the message: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: So I don't believe that I did install pip

Comment: If you install pip, the rest should work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: You probably forgot to check **Add pip to path** during python installation. Rerun the installer (but no need to reinstall), and make sure to add pip to PATH variable, you might have `python3 -m pip` working though